# Is it possible to get information out of install plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to get any information out of the plist used to install an enterprise app onto a device to then store for the app to use.

What I'm trying to do is pass some information to an app on install so that it can then use that information within the app.  I can't make this data static, so it can't be stored in the Info.plist file in the root; it needs to be dynamic and will change on an install by install basis.  I also can't pass the information by a web service etc, it needs to happen on install.

Many thanks,

Davoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're distributing for enterprise (ie not through the App Store), here's a thought: since you can re-codesign an app package after it has been built, and an ipa is simply a renamed zip, why don't you put the app on the server as an unzipped package, and have a server side script insert the settings.plist, zip and codesign the app every time someone downloads the app?

In Summary:

```
1. Compile the package, but don't code-sign it.
2. Place the app folder (*.app) onto a server.
3. When the user downloads it by requesting a link, have the server generate your desired url into a plist and overwrite the existing settings.plist in the bundle
4. Code-sign the package using apple's codesign tool via command line
5. Zip the whole thing and rename to .ipa
6. Serve the package to the client.
```

Comment: Hi,  that's what I was trying to avoid really, it is something I have thought of, but I was afraid of the time to sign for a large bundle (100MB+) which some of the apps will be.  Do you have any idea on performance?  The other issue is that we're running Windows Server, for the boxes which will serve the plist, so we'd need some kind of apple build server.  Thanks for the answer, I'm afraid I think this looks like the only option (as I've been back to the drawing board so many times now!!  Davoc

Comment: Have you tried running the apple codesign tool on cygwin in Windows? It seems like a BSD tool to me.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible due to keychain?